# how to execute/terminate command in the pipe conditionally

Tags: bash, shell

I'm working on a script which need to detect **the first call** to FFMPEG in a program and run a script from then on.

the core code was like:

```
strace -f -etrace=execve <program> 2>&1 | grep <some_pattern> | <run_some_script>
```

The desired behaviours is, when the first **grep**ed result comes out, the script should start. And if nothing matched before `<program>` terminates, the script should be ignored.

The main problem is how to conditionally execute the script based on the grep's output and how to terminate the script after the program terminates.

I think the first one could be solved using **read**, since the **grep**ed text are used as signals, its contents are irrelevant:

```
... | read -N 1 && <run_some_script>
```

and the second could be solved using broken pipe mechanism:

```
<run_some_script> > >(...)
```

but I don't know how to make them work together. Or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2):

You could ask `grep` to just match the pattern once and return and make it return a success error code. Putting this together in a if conditional altogether as

```
if strace -f -etrace=execve <program> 2>&1 | grep -q <some_pattern>; then
    echo 'run a program'
fi
```

The `-q` flag is to suppress the *usual* stdout content returned by the `grep` command as you've mentioned you only want to use `grep` result to perform an action and not use the results.

Or may be you needed to use `coproc` running the command to run in background and check every line of the output produced. Just write a wrapper over the command you want to run as below. The function is *not* needed for single commands but for multiple commands a function would be more relevant.

```
wrapper() { strace -f -etrace=execve <program> 2>&1 ; }
```

Use `coproc` is just similar to running the command in background but provides an easy way to capture the output of the command run

```
coproc outputfd { wrapper; }
```

Now watch the output of the commands run inside `wrapper` by reading from the file descriptor provided by `coproc`. The below code will watch on the output and on the first match of the `pattern` it starts a background job for the command to run and the process id is stored in `pid`.

```
flag=1
while IFS= read -r -u "${outputfd[0]}" output; do
    if [[ $output == *"pattern"* && $flag -eq 1 ]]; then
        flag=0
        command_to_run & pid=$!
    fi
done
```

When the loop terminates, which means the background job started by `coproc` is complete. At that point kill the script started. For safety purposes, see if its alive and do the kill

```
kill "$pid" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: `-q` implies `-m 1` -- it exits immediately on seeing a single match.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe I wasn't clear but I need the script to start before strace finishes. I want the "execve("ffmpeg" ....)" call to triggers the script, grep is just the method I detect it in runtime.

Comment: I'm using a RPI to record some live streams for me. The record script uses a python tool which will call ffmpeg to do the actual recording when there is a 
 valid stream. What I want to do is that when the recording started, I could run a script to display some dynamic information on a GPIO device, and shutdown that device after the record finishes. So the script shouldn't  run after strace terminates. If I read it right, strace in your code will receive a SIGPIPE after grep matches a result, that will kill strace prematurely.

Comment: @YenvY: Could you try the `coproc` approach

Comment: Trying to `kill -0` before sending another signal doesn't add any safety. You get an error message if the process cannot be signaled in either case. The *only* thing this adds is a race condition (the process could die after the `-0` but before the real signal).

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`ifne` util](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/):

```
strace -f -etrace=execve <program> 2>&1 | 
grep <some_pattern> | ifne <some_script>
```